# Is "vertragen" much used in daily speaking or is there another choice?

Tags: usage, speaking

"Vertragen" means "to tolerate", but it has a specific meaning, which is "tolerating sth. physically" not "psychologically".

For example:

> Er kann noch mehr Essen nicht vertragen. (If he eats more he will vomit or be sick.)

Is the word "vertragen" much used in daily German or is there another known possibility to say the above sentence?

Comment: Zwischen "Ich habe die Pilze nicht vertragen" und "Ich habe die irische Volksmusik nicht vertragen" macht man keinen sprachlichen Unterschied, basierend auf der Unterscheidung, ob die Unverträglichkeit psychischer oder physischer Natur ist.

Answer (score 4):

Your example is basically fine, although in my experience (as a native speaker) you wouldn't explicitely mention *Essen* as it is usually clear from the context:
*Willst du noch was? / Willst du einen Nachschlag?* - *Nein, danke! Ich kann nichts mehr vertragen.*
Do you want another serving? - No thanks! I can't eat any more.

Another option is to express it positively (i.e. without negation):
*Nein, danke! Ich bin satt / voll.*
No thanks! I'm full. (Be careful with *voll* though, out of context it denotes saturation with alcohol rather than food ...)

Other examples for *vertragen* would be:

- *Du könntest einen (neuen) Haarschnitt vertragen.*
  You could use a (new) haircut.
- *Die Suppe könnte etwas mehr Salz vertragen.*
  The soup needs some more salt.
- *Er verträgt keine Nüsse.*
  He cannot eat / is allergic to nuts
- *Der verträgt doch nichts!*
  He is a weakling! (colloquial, mostly used with regard to alcohol or enduring (friendly) physical "abuse")

General alternatives are:

- *aushalten* - endure
- *(kann) (ge)brauchen* - could use / need (as in the examples)

As for "much used in daily german": There are many local / dialect alternatives that of course are far more used in daily speech, but for "standard" German you should be good with the above.

EDIT: As Takkat mentioned in his comment, I left out *sich vertragen [mit]* (get along [with each other]). I did so on purpose, as this goes in a completely different direction. But since he mentioned it already, I wanted to at least take it up in English for everyone to read:
- *Wir vertragen uns nicht so gut.*
We don't get along very well.

Comment: *sich vertragen* fehlt noch in der Sammlung alternativer Bedeutungen. Beispiel: *Wir vertragen uns nicht so gut* - *Nach dem Streit vertragen sie sich jetzt wieder prima.*

Answer (score 0):

Let me list three commonly used verbs referring to »taking in food without problems«:

- vertragen
- [bekommen](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/bekommen#Bedeutung6)
- guttun

Examples:

> Man soll nur essen, was man verträgt.
> *(One should only eat what one tolerates.)*
>
> Man soll nur essen, was einem bekommt / guttut.
> *(One should only eat what's beneficial.)*

Your example

> Er kann noch mehr Essen nicht vertragen.

is ambiguous.

> *Meaning A:* He can't stand other food too.
>
> *Meaning B:* He can't stand to eat more.

For B you could say in German unambiguously:

> Noch mehr zu essen kann er nicht vertragen.
> Noch mehr zu essen bekommt ihm nicht.
> Noch mehr zu essen tut ihm nicht gut.

Or with subjunctive:

> Noch mehr zu essen würde er nicht vertragen.
> Noch mehr zu essen würde ihm nicht bekommen / guttun.
>
> Er würde es nicht vertragen, noch mehr zu essen.
> Es würde ihm nicht bekommen / guttun, noch mehr zu essen.